# Does Microsoft Virtual Server 2005 R2 work under Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, virtual-server-2005-r2

I have a laptop that running Windows XP and it's running a virtual machine in the Virtual Server 2005 R2.  Everything works great.

I was thinking of upgrading to Windows 7 and I would like to know whether I can still install Virtual Server 2005 R2 on it and run my virtual machine?

If so, what edition of Windows 7 does Virtual Server 2005 R2 install on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Virtual Server 2005 is not supported on Windows 7 and is intentionally blocked by the Program Compatibility checking system in Windows 7.  Decent instructions on how to disable the Compatibility stuff and get around the problem is documented [here](http://tfl09.blogspot.com/2009/08/windows-7-and-virtual-server.html).

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft does not indicate support for Windows 7

Microsoft Windows Server 2003 Standard Edition, Enterprise Edition, or Datacenter Edition or later

Windows Server 2003 Standard x64 Edition, Enterprise x64 Edition, Datacenter x64 Edition or later versions

Windows Small Business Server 2003 Standard Edition or Premium Edition

Windows XP Professional Service Pack 2 or later (for non-production use only).

Once doscument does indicate Vista will work for non production systemns

Answer (score 0):

Never mind.  Found the [answer](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/w7itprovirt/thread/a98e77b7-95d4-444f-8dbc-630c98074436).

It works with a workaround, but not supported.

Comment: That's the same link that led me to the link I provided in my answer. :)  The problem with everything before the post that has the link I provided is that it's referring to Win 7 Beta and RC, which don't 'block it' intentionally like the release version(s) do. The link I gave you is (more) specifically for dealing with the blocking of it, in the release versions.

Regardless, hope you get it working the way you want. :)

Comment: Thx for the accept! :)  Good luck.